# 'more' command from background thread

Tags: bash

Why does 'more' command produce different output on main and background thread?
Please see example below:

```
#!/bin/sh

test_main()
{
   more input.txt > output_main.txt
}

test_back()
{
   more input.txt > output_back.txt
}

echo "abc" > input.txt
test_back &
test_main
wait
```

output_main.txt:

```
abc
```

output_back.txt:

```
::::::::::::::
input.txt
::::::::::::::
abc
```

Comment: why do you use `more`??

Comment: I'm not sure why, I suspect the answer is "by design". however if you _need_ to use more in a background you can use it like so: `(cat input.txt | more) > out.txt` and retain the same functionality as not running it in the background.

Comment: Actually, I don't have the ability to change the script. Moreover, it works as expected on different environments...

Comment: can you go into more details about which environments it works and which it does not? sounds like that could be important to discovering why

Comment: I have AIX host where it works good, but on OracleLinux 7.0 (inside docker container) and inside Windows 'bash' feature it has strange described behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stdin of `more` must be connected to a terminal to determine the number of lines of a page. When you run `more` in the background, then stdin isn't a terminal and `more` is running in non-interactive mode.

```
$ more input.txt </dev/tty
abc
$ more input.txt </dev/null
::::::::::::::
input.txt
::::::::::::::
abc
```